# Using time in php mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, time

Anybody any idea about this?i don't know with what to replace the (1 minute) in order to work;
`.$checktime['car_date']` is a value in database and is like this 2012-04-14 04:18:14

```
$time=time();

    $checktime=mysql_num_rows($get_cars);
        if($time<$checktime['car_date'] - (1 minute))
        {
        $sqlhour = mysql_query("DELETE FROM car
                    WHERE car_date < current_timestamp - interval '1' minute;");

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that `$checktime['car_date']` is the time is seconds. If so 1 minute is:

```
60
```

So you [would get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php):

```
$time=time();

$checktime=mysql_num_rows($get_cars);
   if($time<($checktime['car_date'] - 60)) {
       $sqlhour = mysql_query("DELETE FROM car WHERE car_date < current_timestamp - interval '1' minute;");
    }
```

**Update**

Since the `$checktime['car_date']` variable is a sql timestamp you should first convert it into `seconds since UNIX epoch`:

```
$currentTime = time();
$carDate = new DateTime($checktime['car_date']);

$checktime = mysql_num_rows($get_cars);
   if($time < ($carDate->format('U') - 60)) {
       $sqlhour = mysql_query("DELETE FROM car WHERE car_date < current_timestamp - interval '1' minute;");
    }
```

Comment: nope i tried this.thanks.$checktime['car_date'] is a value in database and is like this 2012-04-14 04:18:14.

Comment: no.i also try a couple of thinks but nothing.Also tried and this code but againa nothing:  $currentTime = new DateTime();
$checktime = mysql_num_rows($get_cars);
$carDate = new DateTime($checktime['car_date']);


   if( $currentTime->format ('U') < ($carDate->format ('U') - 60)) {
       $sqlhour = mysql_query("DELETE FROM car WHERE car_date < current_timestamp - interval '1' minute;");
    }

Comment: Thanks for the help you were right.First it was a logical error it's +60 not -60. You made some typo mistakes in your answer but you were right about converting it in unix.Thanks again for the help.I edited the right code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly in MySQL, there's no need to manipulate the dates in PHP.

```
DELETE FROM car
WHERE car_date < DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE );
```

If you need to know the IDs of the cars you are deleting then just do a SELECT first, i.e.

```
SELECT id
FROM car
WHERE car_date < DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE );
```

and then loop through and delete them.